# Display hardware fault on Toshiba Satellite Pro laptop

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro C50-A-1E2 laptop (p/n PSCG7E-02C041EN) which has developed a fault on the screen ([4 second video here](https://streamable.com/zpik2)).

An external monitor on the HDMI port works fine.  When it first happened, a little percussive maintenance fixed it for a week or two so I'm sure it's a hardware problem but I don't know whether it's the screen, the motherboard or the cable between them.  It has only the internal Intel HD 4000 graphics.  Could anyone offer a definitive answer?

I was going to ask on Toshiba's forum's but it looks like the answer to all hardware problems there is "return it to a Toshiba Authorized Service center".

Comment: **little percussive maintenance fixed it for a week**  What exactly did this entail? Did you open the laptop up taking all 12+ screws out.  Clean the screen? Flex the lid back and forth??

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience garnered from 27 years in the industry, that appears to be a damaged screen.  I would recommend replacement.  I currently have one in my shop in an identical condition and resolved it by replacing the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @AlphaComp

The motherboard has a single video card, and if it was that the HDMI port would also be affected.  If it was the cable you should be able to go between broken and not by slowly open and closing the lid.  At minimum opening and closing it should change the color patterns displayed. I had never seen a problem like this that wasn't a broken LCD.

A new LCD typically comes with a new cable.

I don't know exact what maintenance you did but it was probably dumb luck.